# Doing an update_all with joins in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, sql-update

It's times like this that Rails' abstraction from raw SQL drives me batty. In MySQL I could do this:

```
UPDATE FROM tasks AS t 
LEFT JOIN projects as p 
ON t.project_id = p.id 
SET t.invoice_id = 7
WHERE p.organization_id == 42
AND t.invoice_id IS NULL
```

How can I do this in Rails 3.0.1 with eager loading? I've tried all of the following:

```
Tasks.joins(:project).where('projects.organization_id' => 42, :invoice_id => nil).update_all( :invoice_id => 7 )
```

And all of the variations of the above. All either gave errors or didn't find anything.

Then I tried to use `scope`:

```
Task.scope :find => {:joins => :project, :conditions => ["projects.organization_id == ? AND invoice_id IS NULL", @organization.id] } do
  Task.update_all :invoice_id => @invoice.id
end
```

This one gave me the error `undefined method 'to_sym' for #<Hash:0x1065c6438>`.

I've spent way too many hours on this, just to replicate a simple SQL query. Please help!

---

**EDIT: Temporary bad solution to get around n+1:**

```
task_ids = Task.select('tasks.id').joins(:project).where('projects.organization_id' => @organization.id, :invoice_id => nil).collect{|t| t.id}
Task.update_all ['invoice_id = ?', @invoice.id], ["id in (#{task_ids.join(',')})"]
```

---

Answer (score 4):

"UPDATE FROM" is not standard SQL, so it's not surprising if it's not directly supported by Active Record.  However, Active Record does give you a way to bypass its abstractions and just issue straight SQL, for those times when you've got to do something it doesn't support.  Inside a model:

```
sql = "UPDATE FROM tasks AS t 
LEFT JOIN projects as p 
ON t.project_id = p.id 
SET t.invoice_id = 7
WHERE p.organization_id == 42
AND t.invoice_id IS NULL"
connection.update_sql(sql)
```

ActiveRecord::Base also has a "select_by_sql" method that lets your non-standard select statements return regular active record model instances.

Comment: Thanks, Wayne. I'd like to abstract if possible because different flavors of SQL handle this kind of query quite differently and I'm worried about it breaking in the future. My example above could be changed to `update tasks, projects set...` and I'd still be having troubles. If you have further thoughts I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @Jed, That would also be non-standard SQL.  I don't know how Active Record would abstract that.  Some things you can do with SQL don't match the CRUD abstraction very well.  This one especially.

Comment: Interesting. So 1+n (non-eager loading) really is the only way to do this in the abstraction layer? I can't believe `scope` doesn't somehow offer a solution. Shouldn't something like my second effort above work? Just going with 1+n for now but definitely not a sustainable solution. Thanks for your help...

Comment: @Jed, "update from" and multiple update depend upon the SQL server.  I'm not sure how those can be implemented on the client side.  Even if they could, I imagine the performance would be dismal, involving at the very least the transfer of every involved record from the SQL server to the client.

Answer (score 3):

I believe at least @ rails 3.0.8 and ARel 2.0.10, we couldn't directly generate UPDATE FROM, but it is possible to get the same result with by resolving the join as a sub-query, e.g.

```
Task.where(:invoice_id=>nil).
where(:project_id=>Project.where(:organization_id=>42).collect(&:id)).
update_all(:invoice_id => 7)
```

This generates SQL like:

```
UPDATE "tasks"
SET "invoice_id" = 7 
WHERE "invoice_id" IS NULL AND "project_id" IN (1,2,3);
-- assuming projects 1,2,3 have organization_id = 42
```

Of ourse, that's resolving the sub-query in Rails not in SQL. To generate a sub-select in SQL, you can mix in a little Arel like this:

```
t = Task.arel_table
p = Project.arel_table
Task.where(:invoice_id=>nil).
where(
  t[:project_id].in(
    p.where(
      p[:organization_id].eq(42)
    ).project(p[:id])
  )
).update_all(:invoice_id => 7)
```

Which generates sql like this:

```
UPDATE "tasks"
SET "invoice_id" = 7 
WHERE "invoice_id" IS NULL 
AND "project_id" IN (
SELECT "projects"."id" FROM "projects" 
WHERE "projects"."organization_id" = 42
);
```

There's a pure ARel way of doing this, but the UpdateManager syntax is woefully under-documented

Answer (score 2):

This is purely ruby/rails, it should not be tagged as SQL --

The only SQL info you could get is : start from another syntactic equivalent instead of the "update from" which is not standard, like for example this (which I wouldn't do either but hey I don't use ruby/rails).

```
UPDATE tasks t
SET t.invoice_id=7 
WHERE 
t.invoice_id IS NULL 
AND 
(SELECT 
p.organization_id 
FROM tasks t2 
LEFT JOIN projects p 
ON t.project_id=p.id 
WHERE t2.id=t.id)=42
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following

```
UPDATE FROM tasks AS t 
LEFT JOIN projects as p 
ON t.project_id = p.id 
SET t.invoice_id = 7
WHERE p.organization_id == 42
AND t.invoice_id IS NULL
```

could be written as the following Arel query:

```
Tasks.include(:projects).where("projects.organization_id = ?", 42).where("tasks.invoice_id IS NULL").update_all("tasks.invoice_id = ?", 7)
```

This assumes that you have the right association between Tasks and Projects.